# Compare two array and change styles of ng-repeat items in angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays, styles, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json like this -

```
[{
    "id": "152",
    "name": "Accounting",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 18:10:57",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 18:10:57"
}, {
    "id": "292",
    "name": "Administration",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 18:37:29",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 18:37:29"
}, {
    "id": "422",
    "name": "Banquet",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 18:43:26",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 18:43:26"
}, {
    "id": "502",
    "name": "Engineering & Maintenance",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 18:47:12",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 18:47:12"
}, {
    "id": "622",
    "name": "Food & Beverage Admin",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 18:51:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 18:51:00"
}, {
    "id": "782",
    "name": "Food & Beverage Service",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 18:56:38",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 18:56:38"
}, {
    "id": "982",
    "name": "Front Office",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 19:05:04",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 19:05:04"
}, {
    "id": "1212",
    "name": "Housekeeping & Laundry",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-20 19:15:48",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-20 19:15:48"
}, {
    "id": "1352",
    "name": "HR",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-21 10:12:38",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-21 10:12:38"
}, {
    "id": "1462",
    "name": "IT",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-21 10:16:14",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-21 10:16:14"
}, {
    "id": "1492",
    "name": "Kitchen / Food Preparation",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-21 10:17:29",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-21 10:17:29"
}, {
    "id": "1712",
    "name": "Purchase",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "created_at": "2016-12-21 10:26:09",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-21 10:26:09"
}]
```

Which I am iterating in list with ng-repeat.

Now I have another array like

```
[152,292,422,1712].
```

Now how do I match the second array with the id of first array and change the style of those matching id's object in the view.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.
The code would look something like this, assuming the Json is saved as foodList:

```
<div ng-repeat="food in foodList"> 
  <div ng-class="{'classNameToWantedStyle': isIDInList(food.id)}">
     {{food.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your controller you would make a corresponding function that returns true if the id is in the list. Here you could use javascripts indextOf method to determine that.

Comment: That is something i wanted . Thanks . I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Thanks Nabarag happy future to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'items' is the name of the array, then you have your ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
```

You can use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) (or [here](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/conditionaldisplay/switch/)) to look at each item then separate that out into sections that you can style differently:

```
<div ng-switch="item.id">
  <div ng-switch-when="152" class="152-class"></div>
  <div ng-switch-when="292" class="292-class"></div>
  <div ng-switch-default class="default-class"></div>
</div>
```

You get the idea, but take a look at the documentation I linked, they might explain it better.

Comment: i appreciate your help rrd . let me take a look . thanks

Comment: well i can not really use ng-switch because those arrays are dynamic and the datas can be anything .